# MySQL Database Normalization and Primary ID's

Tags: mysql, database, normalization

I have a quick question.  I have a database with three tables **Shops**, **Tire_Brands**, and **Accepted_Tires** and for accepted_tires it will just have "id, tire_id, shop_id".

Is it necessary to have the "id" field for accepted_tires.  Will I ever use it, or is it OK to just have "tire_id" and "shop_id" and that's it?

Hope that makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `id` field is not necessary in this case. You could have a complex primary key composed of both `tire_id` and `shop_id` columns because this couple must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't make the structure of your db very clear; if the accepted_tires table is only being used to resolve a many-to-many relationship between the other 2 tables, then no, it doesn't need its own ID

Answer (score 0):

Is any table dependent on Accepted_Tires table? From what I see, it is a NO, now. But, will any table be dependent of Accepted_Tires in future - like a master child? If yes, go for ID now.